# postgreSQL - update a column in the same table

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have a table adresse

```
adr_id | adr_over | adr_debitor |
1      | NULL     | 235567      |
2      | NULL     | 235587      |
~
45678  | 1        | NULL
45679  | 2        | 0
~
```

Now I like to update the column adr_debitor

```
adr_id | adr_over | adr_debitor
1      | NULL     | 235567
2      | NULL     | 235587
~
45678  | 1        | 235567
45679  | 2        | 235587
~
```

I've tried with:

```
UPDATE adresse
  SET adr1.adr_debitor = adr2.adr_debitor
FROM adresse adr1
  INNER JOIN  adresse adr2 
           ON adr1.adr_over = adr2.adr_id
          AND adr1.adr_over IS NOT NULL
```

But there is a syntax error.

Comment: ON adr1.adr_over = adr2.adr_id - this seems to be incorrect
You should be joining on the same column.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `inner join` like that in an update statement. And you also only need to list the joined table, not the target table in the `from` clause:

```
UPDATE adresse adr1
  SET adr1.adr_debitor = adr2.adr_debitor
FROM adresse adr2
WHERE adr1.adr_over = adr2.adr_id
```

The condition `AND adr1.adr_over IS NOT NULL` is not needed as the condition `adr1.adr_over = adr2.adr_id` will only be true if `adr1.adr_over` is not null.

Answer (score 3):

When I did it on mine, it was something like this

```
UPDATE adresse adr1
SET adr_debitor = adr2.adr_debitor
FROM adresse adr2
WHERE adr1.adr_over = adr2.adr_id
```

doing `SET adr1.adr_debitor = adr2.adr_debitor`gave error for me, I did not have to add `adr1.adr_debitor` after SET